# Bdbquit error with Django debugging

Tags: django, debugging

I am a newbie for Django. Although I don't use the `pdb` for debugging but I used before and I removed all pdb methods, I get the `Bdbquit` error with following explanation:

```
/home/mastersnack/dpt2/app/views.py in start
    version = request.session['version']
```

My related code is:

```
def start(request):
        global Big_Matrix
    if 'version' in request.session:
        version = request.session['version']
    else:
        try:
            version = Version.objects.order_by('-id')[0]
        except IndexError:
        return redirect('/')
    if not request.user.id:
        user = User(guest=True, date_joined=datetime.datetime.now(), 
        last_login=datetime.datetime.now())
        user.save()
        request.session["USER_ID"] = user.id
    return redirect('/start')
    rnd = Round(version=version, user=request.user, date=datetime.datetime.now())
    rnd.save()
    products = Product.objects.filter(version=version, selectable=True)
    (a, b, c) = random.sample(products, 3)
    poll = Poll(round=rnd, product_a= a, product_b= b, product_c= c,       
    date=datetime.datetime.now())

    #   (a,b,c)=get_meals(Big_Matrix, [])
    #   poll = Poll(round=rnd, product_a=Product.objects.get(stimuliNum = a, version =    

    version), product_b=Product.objects.get(stimuliNum = b, version = version),    
    product_c=Product.objects.get(stimuliNum = c, version = version),      
    date=datetime.datetime.now())
    poll.save()
    #   (a,b,c)=get_meals(BigMatrix.objects.get(version = version).matrix, [])#bad_ functions)
   #    poll = Poll(round=rnd, product_a=Product.objects.get(oid = a, version =   version), product_b=Product.objects.get(oid = b, version = version),  product_c=Product.objects.get(oid = c, version = version), date=datetime.datetime.now())
   #    poll.save()
return redirect('/preferences')
```

Should I check my code again for the method maybe I forget to remove?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have **removed** all **pdb** methods and that you save your code.
After that if you are running the Django server, **restart** it.

That should do the trick